# antlr visitor: lookup of reserved words efficiently

Tags: c++, antlr

I'm learning Antlr. At this point, I'm writing a little stack-based language as part of my learning process -- think PostScript or Forth. An RPN language. For instance:

10 20 mul

This would push 10 and 20 on the stack and then perform a multiply, which pops two values, multiplies them, and pushes 200. I'm using the visitor pattern. And I find myself writing some code that's kind of insane. There has to be a better way.

Here's a section of my WaveParser.g4 file:

```
any_operator:
    value_operator |
    stack_operator |
    logic_operator |
    math_operator |
    flow_control_operator;

value_operator:
  BIND | DEF
  ;

stack_operator:
  DUP |
  EXCH |
  POP |
  COPY |
  ROLL |
  INDEX |
  CLEAR |
  COUNT
  ;
```

BIND is just the `bind` keyword, etc. So my visitor has this method:

```
antlrcpp::Any WaveVisitor::visitAny_operator(Parser::Any_operatorContext *ctx);
```

And now here's where I'm getting to the very ugly code I'm writing, which leads to the question.

```
Value::Operator op = Value::Operator::NO_OP;

WaveParser::Value_operatorContext * valueOp = ctx->value_operator();
WaveParser::Stack_operatorContext * stackOp = ctx->stack_operator();
WaveParser::Logic_operatorContext * logicOp = ctx->logic_operator();
WaveParser::Math_operatorContext * mathOp = ctx->math_operator();
WaveParser::Flow_control_operatorContext * flowOp = ctx->flow_control_operator();

if (valueOp) {
    if (valueOp->BIND()) {
        op = Value::Operator::BIND;
    }
    else if (valueOp->DEF()) {
        op = Value::Operator::DEF;
    }
}
else if (stackOp) {
    if (stackOp->DUP()) {
        op = Value::Operator::DUP;
    }
    ...
}
...
```

I'm supporting approximately 50 operators, and it's insane that I'm going to have this series of if statements to figure out which operator this is. There must be a better way to do this. I couldn't find a field on the context that mapped to something I could use in a hashmap table.

I don't know if I should make every one of my operators have a separate rule, and use the corresponding method in my visitor, or if what else I'm missing.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ANTLR, it's usually very helpful to label components of your rules, as well as the high level alternatives.

If part of a parser rule can only be one thing with a single type, usually the default accessors are just fine.  But if you have several alternatives that are essentially alternatives for the "same thing", or perhaps you have the same sub-rule reference in a parser rule more than one time and want to differentiate them, it's pretty handy to give them names.  (Once you start doing this and see the impact to the Context classes, it'll become pretty obvious where they provide value.)

Also, when rules have multiple top-level alternatives, it's very handy to give each of them a label.  This will cause ANTLR to generate a separate Context class for each alternative, instead of dumping everything from every alternative into a single class.

(making some stuff up just to get a valid compile)

```
grammar WaveParser
    ;

any_operator
    : value_operator        # val_op
    | stack_operator        # stack_op
    | logic_operator        # logic_op
    | math_operator         # math_op
    | flow_control_operator # flow_op
    ;

value_operator: op = ( BIND | DEF);

stack_operator
    : op = (
        DUP
        | EXCH
        | POP
        | COPY
        | ROLL
        | INDEX
        | CLEAR
        | COUNT
    )
    ;

logic_operator:        op = (AND | OR);
math_operator:         op = (ADD | SUB);
flow_control_operator: op = (FLOW1 | FLOW2);

AND: 'and';
OR:  'or';
ADD: '+';
SUB: '-';

FLOW1: '>>';
FLOW2: '<<';

BIND:  'bind';
DEF:   'def';
DUP:   'dup';
EXCH:  'exch';
POP:   'pop';
COPY:  'copy';
ROLL:  'roll';
INDEX: 'index';
CLEAR: 'clear';
COUNT: 'count';
```

Comment: When I do the first, I get errors like this: error(75): WaveParser.g4:15:6: label op=stack_operator type mismatch with previous definition: op=value_operator. When I do the second, I get slightly different errors: error(124): WaveParser.g4:14:28: rule alt label value_operator conflicts with rule value_operator. I'm really, really new at Antlr, if you can't tell.

Comment: Well, that's what I get for thinking "this is sample, I can just type up the response without testing" (and doing so before I've had enough caffeine.)  Both of the examples were pointing in the right direction, but I missed some details.  I've reworked the answer to provide a bit more context, and put in an example that I've actually generated and compiled (albeit, in Java). This should work much better.

Comment: ah ha! That makes sense now. So my `Value_operatorContext` gets a public `op` variable, and I can `op->getText()` and it gets back to the text of the reserved word in question. Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: I would suspect it's more efficient to use op->getType().  Usually getTest() (at least in Java) has to use start and stop indices into the inputStream to pull out the test, whereas the tokenType will be an int stored directly on the token.